# How to fix overflow on 700K row range

Tags: excel, vba, overflow

As part of a larger macro, the code is supposed to check if the cell in column D starts with a 6. If so, copy the Mid 5 characters starting at the 2nd (so essentially, skip the 6) and if it doesn't start with 6 just copy the first 5 characters from the left and paste into the adjacent cell in column E.

I keep getting an overflow error, I'm assuming because the document is 700K rows long. Any suggestions as to how I fix this?

```
Sub Left_Function()

Dim sourceRang As Range, destinationRange As Range, i As Integer, LastRow As Integer
LastRow = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
Set SourceRange = Sheet1.Range("D1:LastRow")
Set desinationRange = Sheet1.Range("E1:LastRow")
For i = 1 To SourceRange.Count
    For Each cell In SourceRange
        If Left(cell.Value, 1) = "6" Then
            destinationRange(i, 1).Value = Mid(SourceRange(i, 1).Value, 2, 5)
        Else: destinationRange(i, 1).Value = Left(SourceRange(i, 1).Value, 5)
        End If
    Next cell
Next i

End Sub
```

I'm not great at VBA so it's pretty patch-work based on things I've Googled, so if you've got an alternative bit of code then I'm all ears.

Answer (score 2):

There are a lot of issues in your code

- Incorrect use of data type (Integer instead of Long)
- Invalid Range definintion `Range("D1:LastRow")`
- many typos in variable names and object references
- Inconsistent `Worksheet` references (`ActiveSheet` may or may not be `Sheet1`)
- Unnecassary nested For loop (this will blow out your run time)
- For such a large data set, looping the range directly will make the code *very* slow

Fixing these issues, and converting to a Variant Array approach:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Left_Function()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim sourceRange As Range, destinationRange As Range
    Dim i As Long
    Dim src As Variant, dst As Variant

    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    With ws
        Set sourceRange = .Range(.Cells(1, 4), .Cells(.Rows.Count, 4).End(xlUp))
        Set destinationRange = sourceRange.Offset(0, 1)
        src = sourceRange.Value
        ReDim dst(1 To UBound(src, 1), 1 To 1)

        For i = 1 To UBound(src, 1)
            dst(i, 1) = Mid$(src(i, 1), IIf(Left$(src(i, 1), 1) = "6", 2, 1), 5)
        Next

        destinationRange = dst
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the cause of your overflow is that you've specified `i` and `LastRow` as `Int` type. `Int` has a max of `32767`, so if you have 700K rows you'll get an overflow. To fix this change the type to `Long`.

Also the way you're initializing `SourceRange` and `destinationRange` looks wrong for a few reasons --- an expression like `"D1:LastRow"` is just a string literal and will not give a valid range in Excel.

You need something like this:

```
Sheet1.Range("D1:D" & CStr(LastRow))
```

There are 3 things subtle changes here. First, `CStr(LastRow)` converts the numeric `LastRow` to its string equivalent. Second, the `&` concatenates strings (you can also use a `+`). Third, notice the need to *explicitly* specify the column for both the begining AND end of the range: D1:100 is invalid (only one D); but D1:D100 will work.

Hope that helps.